# Why body from the first modal displayed in the second?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to make information windows so that when you press the button - an information window with a description will appear. I wrote the most elementary modal pop-up window, duplicated it, but there was a problem:
Description inside the second and all subsequent pop-ups) is taken only from the first modal window, despite the fact that the text inside the other one. I feel like a complete idiot, but I already tried everything, so I have to ask for help here ...

**Here is jsfiddle example** - https://jsfiddle.net/rw5np6jv/1/

Here is code:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Title 1</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Header:</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">Message - 1</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Button and Modal `div` must have a unique and same **ID**:

```html
<button data-target="#myModal_2" ...>Title 2</button>
<div id="myModal_2" ...>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6mqty0oh/

Answer (score 0):

You did not changed the `data-target` attribute and `div` `class` for the second button. Thats why you were viewing same content on the both buttons.

Checkout this: https://jsfiddle.net/o8d4fjLx/

Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Title 1</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Header:</h4>
  </div>
<div class="modal-body">Message - 1</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Title 2</button>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Header:</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">Message-2</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>
</div>
```